# Does Ansible provide exclusive groups?

Tags: ansible

Is there anyway to say that one host can not be in two groups? For example, as a matter of fact the docs say,

> It is suggested that you define groups based on purpose of the host (roles)

But some of my roles exclude other roles. That is to say they can't overlap. Like production and development. Is there a method to imbue that logic in the groups in the inventory. To be sure that one host isn't attached to two conflicting groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep production and development separate, you want to keep separate inventory-files for them.

That way, you can run the exact same playbook against development, integration and production.

"Production" and "Development" are not groups in the context of the ansible inventory, while "webserver" and "database" are.

A common case is: Install everything on one host in development, but have dedicated database-servers in production.

Your development-inventory would look something alike:

```
[webserver]
host1

[dbserver]
host1
```

and your production-environment something alike:

```
[webserver]
host1

[dbserver]
host2
```

Whenever your roles overlap, you need to write a new role to include the needed profiles.

Comment: But what if an IP address can be provisioned to either, and there is no convention? I don't see how it matters. Regardless what if a webserver excludes a database, or vice-versa.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Is there a method to imbue that logic in the groups in the inventory. To be sure that one host isn't attached to two conflicting groups?"*

A: No. There is no such method in the inventory. But it can be easily implemented in a task. Ansible variable `group_names` keeps the list of the groups a host is a member of. Let's define a list of `exclusive_groups` and test the `intersect`

```
exclusive_groups|intersect(group_names)|length > 1
```

For example, with the inventory

```
$ cat hosts
[group1]
test_01 ansible_host=10.1.0.51
test_02 ansible_host=10.1.0.52

[group2]
test_03 ansible_host=10.1.0.53
test_04 ansible_host=10.1.0.54

[group3]
test_02 ansible_host=10.1.0.52
test_03 ansible_host=10.1.0.53
```

the playbook

```
- hosts: all

  vars:
    exclusive_groups:
      - group1
      - group3

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        member_exclusive_groups: "{{ exclusive_groups|intersect(group_names) }}"
    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
          vars:
            msg: |-
              {{ inventory_hostname }} is member of exclusive groups
              {{ member_exclusive_groups|to_yaml }}
              End of host.
        - meta: end_host
      when: member_exclusive_groups|length > 1
```

gives

```
skipping: [test_01]
ok: [test_02] => {
    "msg": [
        "test_02 is member of exclusive groups", 
        "[group1, group3]", 
        "", 
        "End of host."
    ]
}
skipping: [test_03]
skipping: [test_04]
```

Answer (score 0):

Distilling ideas from other answers, consider this solution. It terminates completely if a host is in multiple exclusive groups.

```
- name: Exclusive group check
  assert:
    msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} may only be in only one of these inventory groups: {{ exclusive_groups|intersect(group_names)|join(',')  }}"
    that:
      - exclusive_groups|intersect(group_names)|length <= 1
```

Set `exclusive_groups` to list of exclusive group names; for example, in inventory:

```
all:
  vars:
    exclusive_groups:
      - webservers
      - databases
```

Place the task so that it's the first thing in the playbook so that it may perform the check and terminate at the earliest opportunity.